# データベース取り扱いソフトウェアなどの控除

Tags: ec-cube

はたしてStackoverflowで質問すべきことなのかどうかというところなのですが、国税局に聞いてもロックオンに聞いてもわからないということで、どなたか知っている方いらっしゃいましたらおしえて頂きたいです。

EC-CUBEは"国際標準化機構及び国際電気標準会議の規格（ISO／IEC）15408に基づき評価及び認証されたの"に該当しますでしょうか。

というものです。データベースなどを扱うソフトウェアは税金の控除を受けられるそうです。私もただの制作現場の人間なのでここら辺りは非常に疎いのですが、どなたかわかる方いましたらおしえてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

なんでロックオンが分からないと答えるのが疑問ですが。
結論からいいますと。2015年2月5日の時点で認証を受けていません。

**評価及び認証された**とある通り。評価や認証を受けたかどうか……。
つまり http://www.ipa.go.jp/security/jisec/index.html を通過したかどうかです。

認証された一覧は、こちらから確認できます。
https://www.ipa.go.jp/security/tax/zeisei_list.html

Comment: Norikaz Ishiiさん、ありがとうございます。なんでロックオンはわからないって答えるんでしょう。というか調べる気が全くない感じでした。一覧ありがとうございます。大変助かりました！